# Add one of 2 values to a cell randomly

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have a cell "A2" and I want to locate on this cell either the initials BA or CF (I want to do this randomly)

How would I able to do that?

So far I have
Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2").value = "BA"

but I don't know what I can do so that from now on it either adds BA or CF randomly.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2").value = IIf(Rnd()>0.5, "BA", "CF")`

Comment: Thank you. If you submit this as an answer I'll select this as an answer.

Comment: Remember that "true random" is hard to achieve but for something simple like this, Tim's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Rnd()` (which produces a random value between 0 and 1)

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2").value = IIf(Rnd()>0.5, "BA", "CF")
```

Comment: Note that without adding the `Randomize` statement before calling the `Rnd()` will mean that the first value will always be the same. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement